# datatable refreshing while selecting dropdown

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, seam

I am developing JSf project with seam, My version is JSF1.2. I am also using Primefaces for the UI. I am looking for the output for dataTable that uses the list of datas providing by the dropdown id value. It needs to change the dataTable while changing the dropdown value. I am confusing lot with the way JSF1.2, because jsf2 is handling this with the f:ajax.

Can anyone suggest the right way in this to proceed? I am getting the dataTable as empty. Please refer my code below.

My XHTML Page:

```
                        <h:form class="input-list">
                            <h:selectOneMenu tabindex="1" id="yearId" value="#{transactionListAction.yearId}">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{yearListAction.yearTypeList}" var="year" itemLabel="#{year.year}" itemValue="#{year.yearId}" />
                                <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" partialSubmit="true" update="datatable" listener="#transactionListAction.yearTransactions}" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>

                            <!-- {RowsPerPageDropdown}-->
                            <p:dataTable id="statementTable" emptyMessage="You dont have Statements in this financial year" value='#{transactionListAction.yearTransactions}' var="transaction" dynamic="false" width="99.9%" loadingMessage="List of Transaction being loaded">
```

ActionClass:

```
            @Name("transactionListAction")
            @Stateless
            @AutoCreate
            public class TransactionListActionImpl implements TransactionListAction {

                @In
                protected TransactionService transactionService;

                private Integer yearId;

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 8649412602585430272L;

                public List<Transaction> getTransactionList() {
                    return transactionService.getAllTransactions();
                }

                public List<Transaction> getYearTransactions() {
                    return transactionService.getByYearId(yearId);
                }

                public Integer getYearId() {
                    return yearId;
                }

                public void setYearId(Integer yearId) {
                    this.yearId = yearId;
                }
            }
```

Error Log:

```
            16:06:52,625 WARN  [lifecycle] JSF1053: (Listener: org.primefaces.application.PostRestoreViewHandler.afterPhase(), Phase ID: RESTORE_VIEW 1,  View ID: /secure/userhome.xhtml) Exception thrown during phase-listener execution: javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.ELException: /secure/userhome.xhtml @38,56 value="#{userListAction.usersList}": Error reading 'usersList' on type org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_seam_29
            16:06:52,625 WARN  [lifecycle] javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:612)
            javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1124)
            javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:451)
            javax.faces.component.UIData.invokeOnComponent(UIData.java:881)
            javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:731)
            javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:675)
            javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:731)
            javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:675)
            javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:731)
            javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:675)
            javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:731)
            javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:675)
            javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:731)
            javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:675)
            javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:731)
            javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:675)
            org.primefaces.application.PostRestoreViewHandler.buildPartialView(PostRestoreViewHandler.java:71)
            org.primefaces.application.PostRestoreViewHandler.afterPhase(PostRestoreViewHandler.java:47)
            com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:175)
            com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:114)
            com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:104)
            com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
            javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
            org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
            org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
            org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
            org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:374)
            org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
            org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
            org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
            org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
            org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
            org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
            org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
            org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
            org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
            org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
            org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
            org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
            org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
            org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
            org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
            org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
            org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
            org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
            org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
            org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
            org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
            org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
            org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
            org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
            org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
            org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
            org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
            org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
            org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
            org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
            org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
            java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

            16:06:52,640 ERROR [SeamPhaseListener] swallowing exception
            java.lang.IllegalStateException: No active conversation context
                at org.jboss.seam.pageflow.Pageflow.instance(Pageflow.java:85)
                at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamNavigationHandler.handleNavigation(SeamNavigationHandler.java:38)
                at org.jboss.seam.navigation.Pages.handleOutcome(Pages.java:653)
                at org.jboss.seam.navigation.Page.preRender(Page.java:313)
                at org.jboss.seam.navigation.Pages.preRender(Pages.java:351)
                at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.preRenderPage(SeamPhaseListener.java:560)
                at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.beforeRenderResponse(SeamPhaseListener.java:471)
                at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.beforeServletPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:147)
                at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.beforePhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:117)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:214)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:96)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
                at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:374)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
                at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

            16:06:52,656 WARN  [Component] Cannot create Seam component, scope is not active: org.jboss.seam.core.conversation(CONVERSATION)
            16:06:52,656 ERROR [viewhandler] Error Rendering View[/secure/userhome.xhtml]
            java.lang.IllegalStateException: No active conversation context
                at org.jboss.seam.core.Conversation.instance(Conversation.java:122)
                at org.jboss.seam.ui.component.UIConversationId.getName(UIConversationId.java:44)
                at org.jboss.seam.ui.util.ViewUrlBuilder.addParameter(ViewUrlBuilder.java:42)
                at org.jboss.seam.ui.component.UISeamCommandBase.getUrl(UISeamCommandBase.java:87)
                at org.jboss.seam.ui.renderkit.LinkRendererBase.doEncodeBegin(LinkRendererBase.java:26)
                at org.jboss.seam.ui.util.cdk.RendererBase.encodeBegin(RendererBase.java:79)
                at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:813)
                at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:934)
                at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:942)
                at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:592)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:109)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
                at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:374)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
                at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
                at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
            16:06:52,671 ERROR [lifecycle] JSF1054: (Phase ID: RENDER_RESPONSE 6, View ID: /secure/userhome.xhtml) Exception thrown during phase execution: javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@f1667e]
            16:06:52,671 WARN  [SeamPhaseListener] uncaught exception, passing to exception handler
            java.lang.IllegalStateException: No active conversation context
                at org.jboss.seam.core.Conversation.instance(Conversation.java:122)
                at org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesManager.prepareBackswitch(FacesManager.java:260)
                at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.afterRenderResponse(SeamPhaseListener.java:503)
                at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.afterServletPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:248)
                at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.afterPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:195)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:175)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:114)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
                at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:374)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
                at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
                at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
                at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
                at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
                at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
                at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
            16:06:52,671 ERROR [SeamPhaseListener] swallowing exception
            java.lang.IllegalStateException: No active conversation context
                at org.jboss.seam.core.Conversation.instance(Conversation.java:122)
                at org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesManager.prepareBackswitch(FacesManager.java:260)
                at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.afterRenderResponse(SeamPhaseListener.java:503)
                at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.afterServletPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:248)
                at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.afterPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:195)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:175)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:114)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
                at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:374)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
                at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
                at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
                at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
                at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
                at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
                at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
                at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle it with ajax in jsf 1.2 also with p:ajax provided by primefaces.

First of all remove `onChange="document.datsForm.submit()"` from `h:selectOneMenu` and add 
as child component of your select menu.

```
   <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" partialSubit="true" update="datatable"  
           listener="#transactionListAction.onYearChange}"/>
```

You haven't given any id to the form contaning datatable which is not a good practice. Give id to the form and refer datatable as `:formId:datatable`. Above `update="datatable"` only works in case if your dropdown and datatable are inside the same form.

Declare method in your action class like

```
         public void onYearChange()   {
            transActionsList = transactionService.getByYearId(yearId); 
         }
```

declare a variable `List<Transaction> transActionsList` in your class and bind it to the value of the datatable. You should not perform any action in getter method because jsf framework calls getters and setters multiple times which results in multiple hits to the db.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I modified the code as Srikanth mentioned.I am using Seam with this jsf project. The dataTable value is showing the datas fine as of now, as I am calling this method value=transactionListAction.yearTransactions, Please correct me if anything I mistaken. So I am calling this same method in listener of ajax, because I am getting the output without issues.

No exeptions while running this, but console shows the following error report while changing the dropdown values.

@Srikanth, can you help me what is going wrong in my flow?

Comment: First of all do not make any database call in getter methods as I mentioned in my answer because getters will called multiple times by jsf framework so your system will become slow if the data involved is huge and it is a very bad practice. And your error says it can't read value="#{userListAction.usersList}". where exactly it is there in your xhtml.

Comment: thanks for your guidance and apologize for the mistaken, even after you suggest in previous reply. I removed the lines and tried again, now everything works good. But while changing the dropdown the datatable doesn't changed. The console says "WARNING: Component "datatable" not found to be updated partially".

Comment: Your xhtml says your datatable id is statementTable and not datatable. I think you have edited your question. Just change it to statementTable from datatable.

Comment: Hello @Srikanth, Thanks for your help. Its working perfectly as I expected. But its only available, if I use the dropdown before this page's action. If I use this dropdown in only current page, it doesn't work out.        Also I am showing the updated dataTable in primefaces light box, for this I need to use another form. I am not able to show the updated table(refreshed table while changing the dropdown) in light box. Can you advise how to do this please?